# Hexagon made in css rendering quite bad in safari (mobile version)

Tags: html, css

Don't know why it's happening, but somehow, My code for an hexagon shape is rendering bad on my phone, Seems to be that is leaving a space between the after and before shapes created to generate the hexagon, here's a screenshot of how it looks:[image: SCREENSHOT]

And this is my actual css code for the hexagon:

CSS

```
.hexagon1 {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%); 
width: 106px; 
height: 61.20px;
background-color: #02cd68;
margin: 30.60px 0;
top:44px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.hexagon1:hover {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #02cd68;
}

.hexagon1:before,
.hexagon1:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 border-left: 53px solid transparent;
 border-right: 53px solid transparent;
 }

 .hexagon1:before {
 bottom: 100%;
 border-bottom: 30.60px solid #02cd68;
 transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
 }

 .hexagon1:after {
 top: 100%;
 width: 0;
 border-top: 30.60px solid #02cd68;
 transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
 }

 .hexagon1:hover:after {
 top: 100%;
 width: 0;
 transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Any suggestion of what could be wrong? something I'm not considering to render it correctly on Safari on my IOS device? because it seems to be working on Desktop version of Safari, Firefox and Chrome

Comment: I can only assume it's something to do with how browsers differ in the way they render sub-pixels. Can you not create the hexagon without decimal pixels? I think if you give it a try without the decimals, it may at least help to demonstrate what the problem is.

Comment: thanks @maddockst I'll try that right now and I'll let you know

Comment: @maddockst my friend It didn't work, the only solution I could find was to add margin-bottom:-1px for the before piece and margin-top:-1px for the :after piece, superposition I guess! hehe